# How to Execute a Database Call after sending a HTTP Response with Spring

Tags: spring-boot

so i basically want to process a HTTP-Post with a Controller in Spring and send back a result for the User AND after that i want to make a database call.

So here is my example:

```
@Controller
public class AngebotController extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private DatabaseUtils dbUtil;
    @Autowired
    private MyMailSender mailSender;

    @RequestMapping(value = REQUEST_PATH, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String doPost(@Valid FormInput input, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        // .. some input validations here
        // after the validation is complete i will have accesss to a object, that i just created, just like the following
        // Lets say that this object holds important values for the database query
        final MyObject validatedInput = new MyObject();

        // Start a new Thread to do the remaining work (the Database Call)
        Thread t = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // so i am starting the database query with the information that i just validated above
                // That Database Query will Return a List of Items based on the given MyObject
                // This Query will take a long time and i dont want the user to wait, because this data is not nessessary for the user
                List<Item> items = dbUtil.getStuffByInput(validatedInput);
                for(Item i : items) {
                    // Now i just want to send some informations about the item via email, this part works
                    mailSender.sendMail("mail@mail.mail", i);
                }
            }
        }.start();

        return "viewname";
    }
}



@Service
public class DatabaseUtils {
    @Autowired
    private ItemRepository repository;

    public List<Item> getStuffByInput(MyObject o) {
        List<Item> items = repository.findAllByMyObject(o);
        // Doing some more stuff with those items here ..
        return items;
    }
}

// The Implementation will be generated by Spring
public interface ItemRepository extends CrudRepository<Item, Long> {
    // will select all Items by comparing the myObject with each Item
    // This also works like intended
    public List<Item> findAllByMyObject(MyObject myObject);
}
```

So where is my Problem?

The only Problem i have is, that the Database Query will end throwing an Exception, because the Database Connection was closed (i guess by Spring)

The Exception: Exception in thread "Thread-6" org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed!

Any Help appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: It seems as if your problem is related to how you access the database to retrieve data. Please provide the relevant code for the database access method 'dbutil.getStuffByInput()'. Also, your title doesn't 'hint' of what the question is. See the help section for more info on how to construct a proper question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: DatabaseUtils is using Spring Data Repositories to fetch Data from my Database. Please check the Updated Post. I just added the DatabaseUtils Class.

And i also changed the Title. I hope it's better now, Thanks